# MapFragment make app crashes at runtime when I try to setMapType

Tags: android, crash, runtime, mapfragment

I have trouble trying to change the type of a GoogleMap in an Android application. I have a basic action bar menu and I would like a map to be placed as a Fragment in my activity when I select the right option in the action bar. Here is my code :

```
package com.example.where2go;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MahMapFrag mapFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    private boolean initializeMap() {
        if (mapFragment == null) {

            mapFragment = new MahMapFrag();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            try{
                if (mapFragment == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("MLOGS", "Map Intitialized");
                    return true;
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_map:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,mapFragment).commit();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
         }
         return true;
     }

}
```

And this is my class that extends MapFragment :

```
package com.example.where2go;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MahMapFrag extends MapFragment {

    public MahMapFrag() {
        Log.d("MLOGS", "CONSTRUCT");
        //this.getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }

}
```

When the line

`this.getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

is commented, the app (seems to) run smoothly. But when the line is uncommented, if I try to change the type of the map in the constructor, the app crashes when I click on my action bar, which call

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,mapFragment).commit();`.

I have a null pointer exception at `com.where2go.MainActivity.onOptionItemSelected`. It've tried several hours to figure out why my mapFragment is null when I set the map type.

Can someone give me a clue and/or explanation about this issue ? I really would like to understand, cause I have the feeling that I'm missing something crucial for further android development....

I use eclipse Juno and Genymotion with Google Play Service installed, and compile with API 19.

Thank you

Qoya

Comment: You may have to wait until the Map view has loaded. Call set MapType in the Fragment's onActivityCreated method and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using I found that helped in mah Case. (reference to your MahMapFrag lol)

> fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

add this to your xml

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/location_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thanks to you I managed to have a SupportMapFragment working. Now I'm struggling with PreferenceFragment Class, which is not available in the Support package :-) I have to admit that I'm a little bit lost with all these packages and the ones you are supposed to use VS. the ones you have to use VS. the many support v.XX packages... And the fragmentManagers associated each time. T_T

Comment: if my answer helped. Please accept it as an answer and ask another question for your new problem.